# (VBA) Custom function refreshing itself with wrong input?

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is hard to explain, therefore I added a picture and also shared the sample excel file via my google drive.

What the function should do: Have different item total prices in row "W" and the percentage of transportation costs within the total prices in row "Q" (several other percentage-rows exist for different cost items, this is just to simplify).
Now I SUM the individual item totals.

Then, I apply below function to all percentages in row "Q", which should then give me the total amount of costs, which I then can devide again by row "W" to get the cost percentage of the total.
In my example file, all sub-percentages are equal, but they could as well be different.

The problem that I encounter occurs when I have two sheets with the function below. For some reasons, whenever the function updates on one sheet (and shows the correct value), the function on the other sheet becomes a mess. When I then manually update ("press enter") on the messed-up function, it shows the correct value, but when I go back to the previous sheet, the function is messed up there... I am going crazy : ( 
And, if I have a third sheet that references "Q" on each sheet, I can never get it to show the correct value for both sheets at the same time, one is always incorrect.

```
Option Explicit
Dim rCell As Range

Function SUMSubCost(rRange As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile
Dim Total
For Each rCell In rRange
  If (Not IsEmpty(rCell)) And (Not IsError(rCell)) Then
    Total = Total + (rCell.Value * Range("W" & rCell.Row).Value)
  Else
  End If
Next rCell
SUMSubCost = Total
End Function
```

[Excel Document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4W0JIpnfttKaEFQX0p1RHVJYkU)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iCLF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a qualifying worksheet object, your `Range("W" & rCell.Row)` will always refer to the ActiveSheet, which is not always the one calling your function.

Here's one way to fix it:

```
Option Explicit


Function SUMSubCost(rRange As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile

    Dim Total, rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In rRange
          If (Not IsEmpty(rCell)) And (Not IsError(rCell)) Then
               Total = Total + (rCell.Value * rCell.Worksheet.Range("W" & rCell.Row).Value)
          End If
    Next rCell
    SUMSubCost = Total
End Function
```

Comment: Dang it, I knew it would refer to the ActiveSheet but I didn't know that the function could be otherwise called in such a way. Thanks!!